# CAP Physics/Math Question involving the normal force and weight

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

A person is standing on a platform that is sliding down the hill as shown in the picture.

The slope of the hill is $30 ^{\circ}$ with respect to the horizontal. The person is standing on a scale positioned on the surface of the platform and the scale is reading only $150$ lbs while his real weight is $160$ lbs.

Whatis the coefficient of kinetic friction between the platform and the slope?

Comment: Whoops, Thanks.

Comment: The picture seems important as the tilt of the scale changes the reading.